# Quais linguagens usar para criar um jogo estilo Tibia/Spout(2D)

Tags: jogos

Olá, eu sempre quis fazer um "joguinho" em 2D no tipo de **[Tibia](http://aondedownloads.s3.amazonaws.com/softwares/26651/3661.jpg)** ou **[Spout](http://indierun.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/4/2/25429350/3044979.jpeg)** (mas para o PC), nada tão complexo, apenas o básico (mapa, fazer o personagem se mover, animação do movimento, etc) e eu gostaria de saber que linguagens eu deveria estudar para conseguir desenvolver algo assim.

Obs: Quero fazer o código do zero, sem usar nenhuma ferramenta.

Tibia
[image]
Spout

[image]

Comment: Qualquer uma, basicamente... Você tem alguma plataforma em mente? (Windows, Linux, Mac, *browsers*, smartphones...) Se não há restrição de plataforma, e você não quer usar nada pronto (por que? é como exercício?) então não tem como responder isso sem ir na opinião de cada um.

Comment: *"Sem usar nenhuma ferramenta"*. Como assim?

Comment: Plataforma Windows.
Unity por exemplo. E sim, é apenas para aprendizado.

Comment: Unity? Hehe Unity é uma *baita* de uma ferramenta... (achei que você queria fazer o basicão mesmo, tipo canvas, OpenGL, coisas desse tipo) Ainda assim, a resposta é mais ou menos a mesma, só muda pra "qualquer uma que o Unity suporta." :)

Comment: Mas então, qual linguagens eu deveria aprender(a mais facil que possa faze oque desejo)??, eu queria fazer tudo do começo, o frame, o mapa, o personagem, etc.

Comment: RPG Maker. Por baixo dos panos ele trabalha com Ruby e já tem varias coisas prontas.

Comment: Como eu disse, prefiro fazer do 0 sem auxilio de ferramentas.

Comment: Se você quer usar Unity, então aprenda C# ou javascript ou Boo (provavelmente C#). Se você quiser fazer por fora do Unity, então javascript e android são promissores. Outras alternativas para C ou C++ seria usar SDL ou Allegro 5. Há milhares de possíveis respostas para a sua pergunta.

Comment: A Mozilla desenvolveu [esse aqui](http://browserquest.mozilla.org/) somente com Javascript (usando websocket). - [src](https://github.com/mozilla/BrowserQuest)

Comment: Amigo C++ ou blueprint essas linguagens voece poderar ver se for usar a plataforma unreal engine 4 por sinal muito boa eu estudo na saga escolaa de games estou produzindo um game 3d porem como vc quer fazer 2d so tera trabalho para fazer as milhes de pixels arts sahsuahsa mais fica a dica use a unreal engine 4 vai facilitar muito a sua vida